# How to create a dataframe which has increasing numbers each time with letter labels?

Tags: r

I do wanna create a data frame which looks like as shown below:

```
c("V2", "V3" , "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20",

"V3" , "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20",

"V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20",

"V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20`",
.
.
.
"V20`")
```

It has to remove first item everytime till last item.

I've tried with following code but it repeats every element.

```
x <- rep(sprintf('V%d', 2:20), c(19:1))
```

Any suggestions to figure it out this problem?

Answer (score 4):

We can go with the explicit apply function or roundabout `sequence`:

```
x[unlist(sapply(2:20, ':', 20))]
```

If you would like to go the functional route with speed tests, see below

---

```
#apply function
fun1 <- function(x) {
  len <- length(x) 
  x[unlist(sapply(2:len, function(n) n:len))]
}

#sequence reverse
fun2 <- function(x) {
  len <- length(x)
  x[rev(c(len, abs(len+1L-sequence(2:(len-1L)))))]
}


#Speed test
x <- paste0("V", 1:1e4)
all.equal(fun1(x), fun2(x))
[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
apply      = fun1(x),
seq_rev = fun2(x)
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
# apply       671.8687  792.1317 1020.802  842.7255  991.182 2553.252   100  a 
# seq_rev    1335.4235 1551.2272 1829.718 1643.3866 1785.616 4250.515   100   b
```

It's little surprise that the `sequence` function is slower given so many function calls.

Answer (score 4):

You could give `data.table::shift()` a try.  It is implemented in C, so should be pretty fast.

```
library(data.table)
c(na.omit(unlist(shift(paste0("V", 1:20), 0:19, type = "lead"))))
```

Other variations, leaving `NA` values intact, are a list result ...

```
shift(paste0("V", 1:20), 0:19, type = "lead")
```

or a data table result ...

```
data.table(x = paste0("V", 1:20))[, shift(x, 0:19, type = "lead")]
```

By the way, in the question you mention you want a data frame.  But what you show there is actually an atomic vector.

Comment: This question seems silly, but in the same spirit as `shift`, there's `paste0("V", sequence(20:1) + rep(0:19, 20:1))`

Comment: @Frank - That's a nice one.  I was experimenting with `sequence(20:1)` as well but couldn't quite get there.

Comment: Data table wish list - I wish there was `fill = NULL` (or `character()`)  available in `shift()` for when we want a list result.

Comment: Yes, I meant vector actually, sorry about that. I have r 3.0.2 version but It doesn't install the data.table package, it says its not available for my version. I checked and its for R (≥ 2.14.1)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not ideal, but this nested for loop does the job:

```
x <- c()
for(i in 2:5) {
  for(j in i:5) {
    x <- c(x, paste0("V", j))
  }
}

x
#  [1] "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V4" "V5" "V5"
```